# How to get rid needle clogging on electrospinning of PLA/PCL/PMMA/Collagen?

Tags: synthesis, polymers, materials

For my thesis research, I dissolved PLA and PCL in chloroform: methanol (3:1), PMMA (350.000 MW, 13 wt%) in acetone, and collagen in acetate acid--and then, I mixed them together. The problem is when I tried to electrospinning with this solution, the needle clogging happened every time. It causes uncontinuous fiber synthesis. Fortunately, when I tried to observe some fibers from the solution, the result was 'no beads' appear.

I use needle 21 G with electrospinning parameters 20 kV and flow rate 2 ml/h.

Is there any suggestions for me on how to get rid needle clogging? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's technical issue.